# How to run salesforce apex trigger on more than 200 records

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I have written a trigger on account object of Salesforce (after insert, before update).

The problem is that when I update 1000 records by writing apex in apex executor, This trigger processes only 200 records.

How can I enable trigger to process more than 200 records?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trigger is run on all records, but in chunks of 200, if you update 1000 records, you trigger will run 5 times with 5 different sets of 200 records.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, I was wrong. My problem was that I was running out of script limit of 2000001. Now Can you please help me to find out how can I make sure I dont go out of that limit by some batchprocessing or something else?

Comment: Hey I have fixed my problem and now a new trouble has come up. When I update my records from data loader, My trigger executes twice. I am actually running this trigger before update and update one field based upon some caluculation.

Comment: That is a new question so please ask a new question rather than stating it in the comments. Also, since you say that superfell is right, I'm sure s/he would appreciate you accepting the answer!